# how would I compare 2 linear models with the same response variable?

Tags: regression, model-comparison

I two have linear models with the same response variable:

(2) y = x1 + x2 + x3

and

(2) y = x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8

what would be a good way to compare them?

I know that if (2) would be y = x1 + x2 then an ANOVA would do (in R).

I checked all the questions, but could not find a related one.

Edit: note that the F-test is about comparing two models that have not only the same response variable, but also the same predictors (see [this handout for example](http://www.analytictech.com/ba762/handouts/comparersquares.htm) ).

Does anyone know if the F-test is also suitable for linear models that only have the (exact) same response variable?

Comment: probably either an information-theoretic approach (AIC, BIC) or [Vuong's test](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1912557)

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks :) I googled for several more hours and AIC definitely fits my needs.